# Module Importing issue

Tags: react-native

When running the app getting the following error. Requiring unknown module "583".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually happens when you have imported something with incorrect path,
Make sure your paths are correct, and not only in your initial component, do check every component.
It happens when you have imported something with a wrong path.